# Trying to join four tables keeps giving me multiple results but each select statement gives what I want

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, union

I have the following two queries:

1. ```
   SELECT     
       CondoFeed2.regionCode, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Resort, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Location,  
       CondoFeed2_Resorts.CheckIn, CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Bed Rooms]
   FROM         
       CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts 
   INNER JOIN
       CondoFeed2 ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[CondoFeed2 ID] = CondoFeed2.[CondoFeed2 ID] 
   INNER JOIN
       CondoFeed2_Resorts ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID]
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT     
       CondoFeed2_More_Info.[front page image]
   FROM         
       [VWR EXPORT CondoFeed] 
   INNER JOIN
       CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts ON [VWR EXPORT CondoFeed].[CondoFeed ID] = CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[CondoFeed2 ID] 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN
       CondoFeed2_More_Info ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_More_Info.[Show All Resorts ID]
   ```

Their results are:

```
regionCode  Resort                                                Location                                   CheckIn       Bed Rooms
----------  ----------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------  ------------  ---------
FLNE        Plantation Island                                     Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  1
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 29, 2012  2
FLNE        Silver Beach Club Resort Condo                        Daytona Beach, FL                          Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 28, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Outrigger Beach Club                                  Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 7, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Outrigger Beach Club                                  Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   Hotel
FLNE        Ocean East Resort Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Sand and Surf Condominium                             Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 8, 2012   1
FLNE        Grand Lakefront Resort Club Usa / Holly Bluff Marina  Deland, FL                                 Sep 9, 2012   2
FLNE        Dolphin Beach Club                                    Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Silver Beach Club Resort Condo                        Daytona Beach, FL                          Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Grand Lakefront Resort Club Usa / Holly Bluff Marina  Deland, FL                                 Sep 1, 2012   2
FLNE        Dolphin Beach Club                                    Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 21, 2012  1
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Dolphin Beach Club                                    Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 8, 2012   2
FLNE        Plantation Island                                     Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   1
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 1, 2012   2
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 29, 2012  1
FLNE        Grand Lakefront Resort                                Club Usa / Holly Bluff Marina  Deland, FL  Sep 29, 2012  2
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Dolphin Beach Club                                    Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Outrigger Beach Club                                  Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  Hotel
FLNE        Sand and Surf Condominium                             Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 29, 2012  1
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 21, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 14, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Ocean East Resort Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Traders Inn Beach Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 29, 2012  1
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Sea Club Iv                                           Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Fantasy Island Resort                                 Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 15, 2012  1
FLNE        Plantation Island                                     Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 21, 2012  1
FLNE        Sea Club Iv                                           Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Ocean East Resort Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Islander Beach Resort                                 New Smyrna Beach, FL                       Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Turtle Inn                                            Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Vacation Villas                                       Titusville, FL                             Sep 22, 2012  1
FLNE        Dolphin Beach Club                                    Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Outrigger Beach Club                                  Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Outrigger Beach Club                                  Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Hotel
FLNE        Grand Lakefront Resort Club Usa / Holly Bluff Marina  Deland, FL                                 Sep 16, 2012  2
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Fantasy Island Resort                                 Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Ocean East Resort Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 15, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Georgian Inn Beach Club                               Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 22, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Ocean East Resort Club                                Ormond Beach, FL                           Sep 8, 2012   Studio
FLNE        Turtle Inn                                            Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 29, 2012  Studio
FLNE        Club Sea Oats                                         Daytona Beach Shores, FL                   Sep 15, 2012  1
FLNE        Grand Lakefront Resort Club Usa / Holly Bluff Marina  Deland, FL                                 Sep 23, 2012  2
```

and

```
front page image
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\a7b45df4501c4f899bc4c5b60f357ae0.jpg
NULL





C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\caecc59b0f5947c8a98f9f44680d551b.jpg

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\6f6465af11fa49338d564ed22de1e97a.jpg

NULL





C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\c76295564f1943bebb66e887ccefc144.jpg



C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\14a99384744c44b49acbf9b3dd8aa91d.jpg
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\9e2dcd00ab0a403585a7a199e8c82f09.jpg
NULL
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\4d54041b95d64625894ec4910699d55b.jpg

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\8625205756c94603a5931065f6f76831.jpg

NULL



C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\03842b7c651b406ab2fb2d3df0d62481.jpg
```

respectively.

The following query yields a single result set however it produces duplicates:

```
SELECT     CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Bed Rooms], CondoFeed2_Resorts.CheckIn, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Location, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Resort, CondoFeed2.regionCode, 
                      CondoFeed2_More_Info.[front page image]
FROM         CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts INNER JOIN
                      CondoFeed2_Resorts ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] INNER JOIN
                      CondoFeed2_More_Info ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_More_Info.[Show All Resorts ID] INNER JOIN
                      CondoFeed2 ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[CondoFeed2 ID] = CondoFeed2.[CondoFeed2 ID]
```

This yields:

```
Bed Rooms  CheckIn       Location  Resort      regionCode                 front page image
---------  ------------  --------  ----------  -------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hotel      May 11, 2013  ACAPULCO, GRO MEXICO  Hotel & Club Aladino's     ACAP  
Hotel      May 11, 2013  ACAPULCO, GRO MEXICO  Hotel & Club Aladino's     ACAP  
Hotel      May 4, 2013   ACAPULCO, GRO MEXICO  Hotel & Club Aladino's     ACAP  
Hotel      May 4, 2013   ACAPULCO, GRO MEXICO  Hotel & Club Aladino's     ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\e06d05f720d344acaafec5d776694301.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\f594d4ee4acc4e6387ac425e6c30ca48.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\59064e6e752d443e89b271b166ab87b9.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\6cdb76a4733c46e2ac2361eda6829861.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\995d8616aa3f4c85a5dd7c365276e113.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\69d05f9cd02e4bd0af5525129116f9a5.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\15293494d88a4d19b25a87d9ab294261.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\0391fdb43e1f4aef85ef2cb8800e2db6.jpg
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
1          Sep 23, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Mayan Sea Garden Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\e06d05f720d344acaafec5d776694301.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\f594d4ee4acc4e6387ac425e6c30ca48.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\59064e6e752d443e89b271b166ab87b9.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\6cdb76a4733c46e2ac2361eda6829861.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\995d8616aa3f4c85a5dd7c365276e113.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\69d05f9cd02e4bd0af5525129116f9a5.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\15293494d88a4d19b25a87d9ab294261.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\0391fdb43e1f4aef85ef2cb8800e2db6.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  The Grand Mayan Acapulco  ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\e06d05f720d344acaafec5d776694301.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\f594d4ee4acc4e6387ac425e6c30ca48.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\59064e6e752d443e89b271b166ab87b9.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Web Ripper\Output\CondoFeed2\Files\6cdb76a4733c46e2ac2361eda6829861.jpg
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP  
Hotel      Sep 2, 2012  Acapulco, GRO MEXICO  Club Vacacional Tortuga   ACAP
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the original data, and the output you're getting, plus the output you would like to get?? With just this pile of SQL and no data, it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do (and where you're seeing multiple rows)

Comment: These two select statements give me what I want individually. However when I try to combine them I get repeated results. I want  CondoFeed2_More_Info.[front page image] to be in the first select statement. ill try to put up some results..

Comment: So **HOW** do you "combine" them?? YOu haven't shown us how you build the complete query.....

Answer (score 2):

The "combined statement" has omitted parts of the constituent queries, such as `VWR Export CondoFeed`.

The following is what I would consider a "simple inner join" of your two queries.  Without knowing your schema and data, testing it is up to you.

```
SELECT     
    CondoFeed2.regionCode, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Resort, CondoFeed2_Resorts.Location,  
    CondoFeed2_Resorts.CheckIn, CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Bed Rooms],
    CondoFeed2_More_Info.[front page image]
FROM         
    CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts 
INNER JOIN
    CondoFeed2 ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[CondoFeed2 ID] = CondoFeed2.[CondoFeed2 ID] 
INNER JOIN
    CondoFeed2_Resorts ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID]
INNER JOIN
    [VWR EXPORT CondoFeed] ON [VWR EXPORT CondoFeed].[CondoFeed ID] = CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[CondoFeed2 ID] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    CondoFeed2_More_Info ON CondoFeed2_Show_All_Resorts.[Show All Resorts ID] = CondoFeed2_More_Info.[Show All Resorts ID]
```

It is not obvious to me why your query was giving you duplicate rows, but an omitted `INNER JOIN` (which did occur in your case) is definitely expected to give you unwanted extra rows.

(Generally, duplicate rows are also often caused by insufficiently specific join conditions which can cause both sides to "multiply" each other.  In a case like yours, it may be useful to check whether the column mentioned in a join condition is the primary key on at least one side of the join, as opposed to being just one column out of many in a composite primary key, or in a multi-column unique constraint.  The simplest fix would then be to add those other columns to the join condition as well.)

Comment: im really a bi novice and am unsure of how to do this union all.

Comment: @user1409298 -  Simply concatenate the two queries and put the `UNION ALL` in the middle.

Comment: @JirkaHanika: That wouldn't work. The queries' resulting sets are very different. Even after you manage to do that (by adding placeholders), I doubt it will be what the OP is after.

Comment: @AndriyM - Fair enough, I hadn't noticed.  The updated question made a hopefully better answer possible.